# How do I get rid of this warning in my React Native test?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs

React tells me to use the `act` test helper but I get this warning:

`Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test? Attempted to log "Warning: You called act(async () => ...) without await. This could lead to unexpected testing behaviour, interleaving multiple act calls and mixing their scopes. You should - await act(async () => ...);".`

Here is my test:

```js
it('navigates to MainScreen on submit', () => {
    const props = createMockNav()
    const setUser = jest.fn()
    const result = renderer.create(
      <MockedProvider mocks={[]}>
        <UserContext.Provider value={{ setUser: setUser }}>
          <LoginScreen {...props} />
        </UserContext.Provider>
      </MockedProvider>
    )
    const testInstance = result.root
    const button = testInstance.findByType(Button)
    expect(button.props.title).toBe('Login!')
    act(async () => {
      button.props.onPress()
      await wait(0);
      expect(props.navigation.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    })
  })
```

I've tried moving things inside or outside the act call but I either break it or still get the warning. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could take a try like this if it could work...

```js
it('navigates to MainScreen on submit', async() => {            //Here  
  const props = createMockNav()
  const setUser = jest.fn()
  const result = renderer.create(
    <MockedProvider mocks={[]}>
      <UserContext.Provider value={{ setUser: setUser }}>
        <LoginScreen {...props} />
      </UserContext.Provider>
    </MockedProvider>
  )
  const testInstance = result.root
  const button = testInstance.findByType(Button)
  expect(button.props.title).toBe('Login!')
  await act( async () => {                                      //And here
    button.props.onPress()
    await wait(0);
    expect(props.navigation.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })
})
```

Comment: Ah nice idea, putting the `async` on the test func. But alas I get:

ReferenceError: wait is not defined
    > 77 |     await act(async () => {

Comment: Oh, the ^ for the problem spot in the failure is under that async. I tried taking the "await wait(0)" out but of course that doesn't work. Thanks for trying!